# Problems with Active Record Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to call some ActiveRecord methods in OrdersController#new action.
I've tested the code in Rails Console and it works the way I intended.
But in the controller action it does not produce the same

```
  order has_many cart_items
  cart has_many cart_items 
  cart_items belong_to order cart_items
  belong_to cart 
  cart_items belong_to product
  product has_many cart_items

def new
  @order.new
  @order.cart_items = current_cart.cart_items
  @order.save

  current_cart.cart_items.destroy_all
end
```

Now current_cart is an application_controller method that checks if the current user has a shopping cart. If it does it pulls that cart from the database and if the user does not then it creates a new cart for the user. What I am trying to do here is when the user finalizes their order I'm trying to transfer the cart_items from current_cart to orders then clear the shopping cart.

When I do this in rails console, it gives me what I want. Order with cart_items that were in current_cart, and after I run destroy_all on the cart I have an empty active record association array.

When I test this in my controller both Order and Cart return an empty active association array.

What is going on here?

```
    #application controller method of finding current_users cart
    def current_cart
    # if user is logged in
    if current_user
      @user = current_user
      # checking user to see if account is confirmed and verified
      if @user.confirmed_at != nil

        # checking if user already has cart in cart database
        if Cart.find_by(users_id: @user.id) != nil
          # find a row in the database where users_id: equal to @user.id
          # where clause does not work here
          cart = Cart.find_by(users_id: @user.id)
          session[:cart_id] = cart.id
          cart.save
          #establish Cart session cart for user
          Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
        else
          # create a new Cart Object for user.assign current_user's id to cart object
          cart = Cart.new
          cart.users_id = @user.id
          # save it to get cart id assign session[:cart_id] == cart.id
          cart.save
          session[:cart_id] = cart.id
        end
      end
    end
  end



class CartItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cart_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
# scope for most_recent and subtotal
# find out if rails sorts on update column cuz this is annoying.


  def create
    # grabbing cart from application controller current_cart method
    @cart = current_cart
    # session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    # individual product items get added to cart item and added to cart and saved
    @cart_item = @cart.cart_items.build(cart_item_params)
    @cart.save
  end

  def update
    @cart = current_cart
    # finding cart_items by cart_id
    @cart_item = @cart.cart_items.find(params[:id])
    # @cart_items.order(:id)
    @cart_item.update_attributes(cart_item_params)
    @cart_items = @cart.cart_items.order(:id)
    # redirect 'cart_show_path'
    @cart.save
  end

  def destroy
    @cart = current_cart
    @cart_item = @cart.cart_items.find(params[:id])
    @cart_item.destroy
    @cart_items = @cart.cart_items
    @cart.save
  end

  private
    def set_cart_item
      @cart_item = CartItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    def cart_item_params
      params.require(:cart_item).permit(:cart_id, :product_id, :unit_price, :quantity, :total_price)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, figured it out.

I was using @order.save which was not processing the error message!!!!!!!!
After @order.save! it gave me the validation error in another model.
I commented that out and it worked.

I iterated current.cart_items and assigned the cart_id to nil and order_id  to @order.id essentially clearing the cart and "transferring" the items over.

I couldn't figure out a way using destroy_all though. I think this is impossible like @Sri said.

Thanks alot!

So the end code was this:

```
@order = Order.create!(users_id: current_cart.users_id)

current_cart.cart_items.each do |item|
  item.order_id = @order.id
  item.save!
end

if @order.save
  current_cart.cart_items.each do |item|
  item.cart_id = nil
  item.save!
end
```

Answer (score 2):

When you say you are transferring the `cart_items` from `current_cart` you are passing on the objects, you are not creating new `cart_items` (which means the database ids are same) and when you do `current_cart.cart_items.destroy_all` it is deleting them from the database. See [ActiveRecord::Relation#destroy_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all)

For you use case, its enough if you just do

```
def new
  @order.new
  @order.cart_items = current_cart.cart_items
  @order.save

  current_cart.cart_items = []
end
```

Comment: Vishnu That does not work. When I go into rails console. I'm still getting empty arrays for both Order and Cart.

Comment: are you sure `@order.save` was successful? May be there are some validation errors? Try `@order.save!` and it will raise error if validations fail. It would be more helpful if you could show us how you are initialising  `current_cart` and its `cart_items`

Comment: Yes I'm sure @order.save was successful. because I clear the records in the db with Order.destroy_all and CartItems.destroy_all run the action and get a new order record/objet generate in Rails Console. I tried save! and there were no errors. I'll put up some debugging code soon.

Comment: I've tried iterating over current_cart.cart_items.each do |item| item.cart_id = nil end.

I've tried current_cart.cart_items.destroy_all.

I've also tried current_cart.cart_items = [].

It seems to clear both order.cart_items and current_cart.cart_items when I do the last two.

The first option setting the cart_id = nil seems to work for the first order. Then any more orders has the cart_items stay in current_cart.